# Not able to create child Process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I am working on a log tail project using node.js but the function `process.createChildProcess` is not working.Is there any alternative to that?

```
var sys = require('sys');
var filename = "test.txt";
var process=require('process')

if (!filename)
  return sys.puts("Usage: node watcher.js filename");

// Look at http://nodejs.org/api.html#_child_processes for detail.

var tail = process.createChildProcess("tail", ["-f", filename]);
sys.puts("start tailing");

tail.addListener("output", function (data) {
  sys.puts(data);
});

// From nodejs.org/jsconf.pdf slide 56
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(req,res){
  res.sendHeader(200,{"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  tail.addListener("output", function (data) {
    res.sendBody(data);
  });
}).listen(8000);
```

Here I am getting error:

```
var tail = process.createChildProcess("tail", ["-f", filename]);
                   ^

TypeError: process.createChildProcess is not a function
```

Any help will be appreciated

Article referred: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spawn` for creating a child process in Node.JS.
Here's an example based on your code:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
/* Some Code Here! */
var tail = spawn("tail", ["-f", filename]);
```